# How to write bigquery function to return table after this error

Tags: function, google-bigquery

I am writing a function from the Biquery dataset clusterdata_2011_1 to return a table. I still couldn't figure it out after looking at formate in here[Standard SQL user-defined functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#templated-sql-udf-parameters)

```
CREATE FUNCTION `google.com:google-cluster-data.clusterdata_2011_1.task_events` .FnGetTotalSubmitTasks (mach_id bigint(20), tm timestamp) RETURNS bigint
          DETERMINISTIC 
AS
(

SELECT COUNT(*)
from
(
SELECT distinct e.job_id, e.task_index
 
      from `google.com:google-cluster-data.clusterdata_2011_1.task_events` as  e 

 
where e.machine_id= mach_id and e.event_type in (1) and e.canonical_time = tm  
group by e.canonical_time

   ) as topF  );
   

select
        e.canonical_time,
        e.machine_id,
        FnGetTotalSubmitTasks(e.machine_id, e.canonical_time) as total_Fail_number
        
        from `google.com:google-cluster-data.clusterdata_2011_1.task_events` as e
     
    group by e.machine_id, e.canonical_time;
```

but this error showed:

```
The body of each CREATE FUNCTION statement is an expression, not a query; to use a query as an expression, the query must be wrapped with additional parentheses to make it a scalar subquery expression at [8:1]
```

[error under SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bs30.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION `google.com:google-cluster-data.clusterdata_2011_1.task_events` .FnGetTotalSubmitTasks (mach_id bigint(20), tm timestamp) RETURNS bigint
          DETERMINISTIC 
AS
(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM
      (SELECT distinct e.job_id, e.task_index 
        from `google.com:google-cluster-data.clusterdata_2011_1.task_events` as  e  
        where e.machine_id= mach_id and e.event_type in (1) and e.canonical_time = tm  
        group by e.canonical_time
      ) as topF  
  )
);
```